# Algebra of compact operators on $\ell_p$

Tags: banach-spaces, banach-algebras, compact-operators

Are the algebras of compact operators $K(\ell_p)$ and $K(\ell_q)$ isomorphic as Banach algebras for $1\leq p<q<\infty$?

Comment: If $p=q'$ they are isomorphic because $K(\ell_r)=\ell_{r}\otimes_\epsilon\ell_{r'}$ for $1<r<\infty$

Comment: @Norbert, but they are not isomorphic as Banach algebras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, they are not isomorphic as Banach algebras. By the proof of Eidelheit's theorem, if $A_1$ and $A_2$ are subalgebras, respectively, of $B(X)$ and $B(Y)$ that contain all finite-rank operators, ($X$ and $Y$ are Banach spaces) and are Banach-algebra isomorphic, then $X$ and $Y$ are Banach-space isomorphic.

This was rediscovered [in this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-11/S0002-9939-06-08375-4/S0002-9939-06-08375-4.pdf) which surprisingly does not mention Eidelheit's result.

Comment: Very nice answer, as usually.

Comment: Do you have a reference for Eidelheit's theorem?

Comment: @cyc, M. Eidelheit, On isomorphisms of rings of linear operators, *Studia Math.* **9** (1940), 97–105.