# If B(X) is isomorphic to B(Y), does that mean X is isomorphic to Y (for X and Y Banach spaces)?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces such that $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is linearly isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ (where $\mathcal{B}(\cdot)$ denotes the algebra of bounded linear operators).  Must it always be the case that $X$ is therefore isomorphic to $Y$?

I suspect this is not true, but I can't immediately see how to produce a counter-example.  Surely, whether it is true or false, this must be well-known.

Comment: How do you want $B(X)$ and $B(Y)$ to be isomorphic? Just as Banach spaces or also as Banach algebras? I suspect the answer might depend on this.

Comment: Just as Banach spaces.  Actually, I never really thought about two Banach algebras being isomorphic in an algebraic sense.  I wonder if the answer is different depending on the sense of isomorphism given.

Comment: A closely [related question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1697759/algebra-of-compact-operators-on-ell-p/1698445#1698445)

Comment: @Norbert thank you. So it seems that Cameron's question was important, as an algebraic isomorphism between $\mathcal{B}(X)$ and $\mathcal{B}(Y)$ implies that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic as Banach spaces. But I am still interested in an answer to the Banach space isomorphism question.

Comment: Are you interested in isometric isomorphisms or arbitrary ones?

Comment: @Norbert arbitrary ones.  Isometries are not required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ben, the answer is **no**.

Note that if $X$ is reflexive, then $B(X)$ is isometric to $B(X^*)$ via $T\mapsto T^*$. Note that this map is an anti-isomorphism of Banach algebras.

As for less trivial examples, $B(\ell_p)$ is Banach-space isomorphic to $B(L_p)$ as well to $B(X)$ for any other separable, infinite-dimensional $\mathscr{L}_p$-space and $\ell_p$ is not isomorphic to $L_p$ unless $p=2$. This was observed by [Arias and Farmer](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102364179)  but I suppose it had been known before to the big shots in the field.